# Redirect plugged gutter downspout drain

Tags: drain, drainage, pvc, gutters, downspout

The rear gutter downspout drain at the back of my house is apparently clogged (or crushed, or overgrown with roots). The previous homeowner said a nearby window well flooded due to the overflow and then redirected the drain onto the paver walkway. This is working decently but leads to a few undesirable outcomes: icy walkway in winter, excess water on pavers, likely excess wear on pavers.

I tried to flush the clogged drain and augured it with no success. Rather than scope it or repair the existing one (likely corrugated plastic), I am thinking about putting in a new PVC drain in a straight line from the gutter downspout to a pop-up emitter at my fence line about 10 feet away. This area seems to be where my or a neighbor’s French drain is; it already collects a lot of water so a future option is to add/fix the existing French drain.

To add the new downspout drain I would have to remove probably 12” path of pavers, trench, add pipe, then restore the pavers. Is there anything else I should consider before starting?

Any thoughts much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Image of gutter downspout drain and paver walkway area]

Comment: I'm not sanguine about popups for drains.  Would it be possible to redirect this downspout elsewhere?

Comment: Hmm, I don’t think so. This picture is from the back of the house, facing towards the street, which is where the lot elevation slopes. 

The current downspout is bounded by the house, a patio wall, the pavers pictured, and the AC unit/shed (shown). 

Unless I’m missing a more obvious outlet, I think heading to the fence line is the most direct and distant from house option.

Comment: Is your gutter lower than (what I'm assuming is) the garage roof?

Comment: The downspout in question comes from the rear of the house (2nd story gutter). Garage roof is 1st story.

Comment: Would you consider running a diagonal downspout across the side of the house, then dropping down to the ground in the front?  Aesthetics are...different...but it would be more functional.